# How to apply gradient color in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I am making a line chart using chart.js library and here I would like to change the color of the line to gradient color.

Code I have tried,

```
  const gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
  gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
  gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "#f49080");
```

And added it in dataSets like,

```
datasets: [
  {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    backgroundColor: gradientFill,
    .
    .
  }
]
```

But I couldn't see the changes and still some gray color line only gets displayed instead of gradient.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit Chart.js React Typescript (forked)]

**Edit:** Tried adding `borderColor : gradientFill` but that also doesn't work.

**Requirement:** Requirement is that I need to have a gradient line similar like https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKGqT.png

Kindly please help me to change the color to gradient color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442223/2358409 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/63900136/2358409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradient does not apply because of your `useEffect` hook, in this hook you set the data again with your `formatData` function but only pass the data and no canvasGradient. So you will need to pass that too.

See with lines 108 and 109 commented out it works fine, so you will need to either recreate the gradient there or create it on a higher level so you only create it once.
https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-react-typescript-forked-dxlj7?file=/src/App.tsx

**Edit:**

Updated to different method, in your `formatData` function for the backgroundColor use ternary operator to check if canvas gradient is given if not take the current backgroundColor

Comment: Sorry I have removed few line of code to make it simple but as per your solution, that won't work in that case. Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-react-typescript-forked-3p2oc  . Here if user clicks on the change button, the update should happen but it doesn't happen if we comment the line 108 and 109.

Comment: Nothing changed much, just added button to update the data points. (Which was there earlier and removed it to reduce the complexity of the question). Could you please look into the above commented sandbox for the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I litterly used the sandbox you linked in your question and you can see it working, its not gray but one big color?

Comment: Yes, agreed. And I apologize for not making this statement in question. But unable to update the change if there was a button and which is why I have made the update code inside ```useEffect``` .

Comment: Yeah so you will need to pass the gradient to your usefeect state in some way or use another function that does not expect a background color so you dont set it to undefined

Comment: It is only possible to set gradient inside ```canvasCallback``` function, so unable to get it outside of this function and pass it down as dependency in ```useEffect``` .

Comment: Then you fist check if its undefined if not you can set it if its undefined dont set it

Comment: Thanks for editing the sandbox. But it has warnings like ```Object is possibly 'null'.``` which will prevent my app from compiling in real environment even though it works in the sandbox here. Hope you understand.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `borderColor : 'Red'` in the datasets. see below code

```
datasets: [
      {
        pointBorderWidth: 10,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 3,
        fill: "start",
        backgroundColor: gradientFill,
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor : 'Red',   //  New line added
        data
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I need to assign gradient color. If I replace red with `borderColor : gradientFill`, then its not working. Could you please guide here?

Comment: You can't add gradientFill here because gradientFill is an object and you have to specify hexcode of any color value or any color name.

Comment: My requirement is that I need to have a gradient color line like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKGqT.png . So can't give color name directly like red or some other.

Comment: Follow this https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/ygvjMX

Comment: Yes I have already tried that but when I give that inside my react app, it is not working. Even you can fork my above given example in the question and include it. If it works please update the answer.