# Object is possibly 'null' react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks, chart.js

I am making a chart in react app with typescript and implementation wise things are completed.

Issue is that I am receiving the error in the line,

```
backgroundColor: gradientFill
          ? gradientFill
          : chartRef.current.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor,
```

Error states that,

> Object is possibly 'null'.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit Chart.js React Typescript (forked)]

Error occurs in line number **24** .

**Things tried:**

```
chartRef?.current?.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor
```

This results in the error `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'never'.`.

Could you please kindly help me to get rid of the error? Thanks in advance.

**Context:** This question is related to my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70471027/15916627) and [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473154/15916627).

Comment: refactor the `formatData` function to return that object if(chartRef.current) else return some valid object or whatever

Answer (score 0):

If nothings seems to work you can disable type checking for a particular line by adding following comment (only if there is no other way to just work around with it)

```js
// ...other styles
// @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
backgroundColor: gradientFill
          ? gradientFill
          : chartRef.current.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor,
//...other styles
```

Comment: Sorry, these kind of implementation are strictly banned by my team. We need to implement proper type checking then and there.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that `chartRef.current` is not defined, so you need to check that it exists before you can access the `data` property on it:

```
backgroundColor:
          chartRef?.current?.data?.datasets
            ? chartRef.current.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor
            : gradientFill,
```

I would also recommend moving the definition of `chartRef` to be above the `formatData` function which accesses it.

Comment: I have implemented your solution here https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-react-typescript-forked-ewk85 but it ends up in different error.

Comment: @ewk85 My apologies, I had the ternary the wrong way round, I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Object is possibly 'null'.

That is actually correct. In fact, the type of `chartRef` is `React.MutableRefObject<Chart | null>`, thus it's `current` property is either a `Chart` or `null`. If you are sure it will not be null when accessing the getter, you can use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), ie. `!`. So you'd do this:

`chartRef.current!`

Here, you are allowed to call methods on it, or access properties, eg. `data`.

However, you'll see that `dataset` may be `undefined`. Therefore, you should either implement some conditional logic to check if it has a value, or -- again -- if you are sure it will have a value, then use the same operator:

```
backgroundColor: gradientFill
          ? gradientFill
          : chartRef.current!.data.datasets![0].backgroundColor
```